# Check whether a variable is instance of ResNet50

Tags: python, keras, instance

I am checking whether

```
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling="avg")
```

is instance of

```
keras.applications.ResNet50
```

What I have done is:

```
isinstance(model, ResNet50)
```

but unfortunately this is raising me the following exception:

> TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union

Moreover, I have tried:

```
isinstance(model, keras.applications.ResNet50())
```

but, again, this is raising me the same exception.

- What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`keras.applications.ResNet50`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/resnet.py#L504) is a function that returns an instance of [`keras.models.Model`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L68).

Try:

```
if model.name == "resnet50":
    ...
```